# How to launch 'Google settings' from your Android app code?

Tags: android, service, notifications, settings

How to open `Google Settings` from your app so the user could enable `Notifications for Google Play Services` to receive invitations for multiplayer network game?
`Google Settings -> Play Games -> Notifications` (Allow games to send requests and notifications)

Comment: Thanks you for answer. Unfortunately the default settings do not include options for Play Games for at least Android 2.2 :(

Answer (score 0):

I found answer:

```
   Intent settings = new Intent();
   settings.setPackage("com.google.android.gms");
   settings.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
   starrtActivity(settings);
```